# Describe extended table equivalent in spark / show nested structure

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am learning spark. I have a table with a structure nested and i want to see the structures members.

I am trying to do

```
describe table
describe extended table
```

I get a table with its members but the table doesn't show the members of the structures. 
How do i see the structure members?

Comment: I generally used to view schema like this using SparkSQL for hive. try this. hiveContext.hql("DESCRIBE formatted xyz").collect().foreach(println)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use this :
**SparkSQL**

```
hiveContext.sql("DESCRIBE FORMATTED table_name").collect().foreach(println)
```

Another method :

```
hiveContext.tables.foreach(println)
```